# CMS magnetic field outside

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider, inductance

The magnetic field at CMS is often given as 4 T.
According to [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Compact_Muon_Solenoid#/media/File:CMS_Slice.png) the field outside the solenoid is just 2 T.
Is this just because the field of a solenoid is not constant and decreases with distance?
Or is there another effect, or perhaps a second source for the magnetic field in the muon chambers, not related to the solenoid of CMS?

Comment: For an infinitely long solenoid the external field would be zero, but since all the magnetic field lines are closed and in a short solenoid the field has to return close to the solenoid, the field on the outside will be strong. CMS has a steel return yoke and steel typically saturates at about 1-1.5T, so the yoke wouldn't do much if the field was much larger than 2T. If I remember correctly, the field on the outside is also used for tracking, but I would have to go back to the CMS documentation for the details.

Comment: I confirm that the field at the outside (around 2T) is used for tracking the muons. A side remark, the magnetic field of CMS at the center of the detector is 3.8T (not 4 as initially foreseen).